# efficient way of matching coordinates

Tags: c#, dictionary, coordinates

I have 2 lists of coordinates in C# one as of coordinates of Drivers and the other as of coordinates of cafes. I am looking for an efficient way of populating a static Dictionary with its key as of a Driver from the first list and its associated values of all Cafes in 500 meters radius.

```
public void ManageList() {
  GlobalList.Clear();
  foreach (var driver in driverList)
        {
            var driverCoords = new GeoCoordinate(driver.Latitude, driver.Longitude);
            List<Cafe> matchedCafes = new List<Cafe>();

            foreach (var cafe in cafeList)
            {
                var cafeCoords = new GeoCoordinate(cafe.Latitude, cafe.Longitude);

                if (cafeCoords.GetDistanceTo(driverCoords) <= 500) {
                    matchedCafes.Add(cafeCoords);
                }
            }

            GlobalList.Add(driverCoords, matchedCafes);
        }
}
```

the above works fine as long as drivers are not movable objects. If I want to send the driver's coordinates every 5 seconds and update the GlobalList per driver the above algorithm fails as I am basically clearing the whole list and populate it again.

Comment: Don’t use a global, then

Comment: Surely, these days this would be done in the cloud using Algolia or similar

Comment: Maybe you should state **how many** are in each list, the problem domain changes.

Comment: There's no real way to avoid iterating over all cafes to check if they are within range of the particular driver. You could perhaps compare driver coordinates with previous values and not update their list if their coordinates haven't changed (below a certain threshold)

Comment: On second thought, if the list of cafes is really big and the division of discrete coordinates per 500 meters (I admit I have no idea how many "whole" coordinates fit in that range) is small, you can hold multiple maps of cafes based on coordinate boxes thereby eliminating the need to query most of them each iteration. Edit: Just now @Fattie wrote an answer suggesting this method.

Comment: hi @o_weisman - this is a well-known problem in graphical computing.  indeed every single time you play any game, zillions of these calculations are going on.  The solution is by no means simple, but you can make it incredibly more efficient than the raw approach.

Comment: @Fattie See my comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a pointer than an answer.  It's unclear **how many** items you are talking about.

But really what you describe is a **spatial hashing** problem.

This is a basic of game engine, physics, programming.

It is a big topic, but you could google to get started,

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/redesign-your-display-list-with-spatial-hashes--cms-27586

http://zufallsgenerator.github.io/2014/01/26/visually-comparing-algorithms/

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/69794/86883

As a matter of fact, you could probably ask your question on gamedev, since, it is exactly that type of question.

I'll try to make an extremely simple explanation:

- Say your system performs perfectly fine (no performance problems) when you have, example, 20 cafes.
- But, in fact you have 2000 cafes.
- So break down the map into about 100 "boxes".
- When you do a taxi, *only do the cafes in that box*.

You've immediately eliminated 1980 of the cafes which are so far away they are not even in the box in question. (Naturally what I have stated is a simplification, there are a huge number of details to address in the basic approach.)

Actually this article -

https://dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-spatial

very nicely explains both quadtrees and geohashing for you.